# log4j2 logs cannot be stored in the specified folder

Tags: java, log4j2

Here is the logging configuration file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--status:log4j包内部日志等级 600s刷新一次配置 -->
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="600">
    <!-- 参数声明 -->
    <Properties>
        <!-- 日志文件存放根路径 -->
        <property name="DEFAULT_LOG_ROOT_PATH" value="./run"/>

        <!-- 日志格式1 -->
        <property name="LOG_PATTERN"
                  value="[ %X{traceId} ] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} -- %style{[%t]}{bright,magenta} %highlight{%-5level}{ERROR=Bright RED, WARN=Bright Yellow, INFO=Bright Green, DEBUG=Bright Cyan, TRACE=Bright White} %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n"/>

        <!-- 日志格式2 完全自定义-->
        <property name="INIT_INFO_PATTERN" value="%msg%n"/>

        <!-- 日志文件最大文件大小全局配置,单位可以为KB、MB或GB，一天之内最大文件产生数量全局配置 -->
        <property name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10KB"/>
        <property name="MAX_FILE_NUM" value="2"/>

        <!-- debug 日志文件位置及名称，在rollFile的时候老文件的生成规则 -->
        <property name="DEBUG_FILE_PATH_ING" value="${DEFAULT_LOG_ROOT_PATH}/logs/current/debug.log"/>
         <!--  filePattern="${LOG_HOME}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/${FILE_NAME}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz"> 备份时使用gz格式压缩-->
        <property name="DEBUG_FILE_PATH_ED"
                  value="${DEFAULT_LOG_ROOT_PATH}/logs/history/$${date:yyyy-MM-dd}/debug-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log"/>

        <!-- info 日志文件位置及名称，在rollFile的时候老文件的生成规则 -->
        <property name="INFO_FILE_PATH_ING" value="${DEFAULT_LOG_ROOT_PATH}/logs/current/info.log"/>
        <property name="INFO_FILE_PATH_ED"
                  value="${DEFAULT_LOG_ROOT_PATH}/logs/history/$${date:yyyy-MM-dd}/info-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log"/>

        <!-- error 日志文件位置及名称，在rollFile的时候老文件的生成规则 -->
        <property name="ERROR_FILE_PATH_ING" value="${DEFAULT_LOG_ROOT_PATH}/logs/current/error.log"/>
        <property name="ERROR_FILE_PATH_ED"
                  value="${DEFAULT_LOG_ROOT_PATH}/logs/history/$${date:yyyy-MM-dd}/error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log"/>

        <!-- warn 日志文件位置及名称，在rollFile的时候老文件的生成规则 -->
        <property name="WARN_FILE_PATH_ING" value="${DEFAULT_LOG_ROOT_PATH}/logs/current/warn_error.log"/>
        <property name="WARN_FILE_PATH_ED"
                  value="${DEFAULT_LOG_ROOT_PATH}/logs/history/$${date:yyyy-MM-dd}/warn_error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log"/>

        <!-- init 日志文件位置及名称，在rollFile的时候老文件的生成规则 -->
        <property name="pathNow_Init" value="./init.log"/>
    </Properties>

    <!--输出终端-->
    <appenders>
        <!-- 控制台 -->
        <console name="Console_Log" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </console>

        <!-- 加载信息文件打印,由append属性:每次运行程序会自动清空 -->
        <File name="initInfoAppender" fileName="${pathNow_Init}" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${INIT_INFO_PATTERN}"/>
        </File>

        <!-- info日志文件输出日志信息 -->
        <RollingFile name="Info_File" fileName="INFO_FILE_PATH_ING" filePattern="${INFO_FILE_PATH_ED}">
            <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <!--日志 行样式-->
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="${MAX_FILE_SIZE}" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="${MAX_FILE_NUM}"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </appenders>

    <!--配置总的日志监听级别-->
    <loggers>
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="Console_Log"/>
          <!--  <appender-ref ref="Debug_File"/>-->
            <appender-ref ref="Info_File"/>
            <appender-ref ref="Error_File"/>
        </root>

        <!-- 自定义logger,additivity=false标识不走root模式输出日志-->
        <logger name="init" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="initInfoAppender"/>
        </logger>

    </loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Taking info as an example, the purpose is to think that the current directory exists on the current day, and the history exists in the yyyy-MM-dd folder in the history directory.
But after the project actually runs, it has this effect.

```bash
-- current
---- info.log
-- history
---- 2022-06-29
------ info-2022-06-29.1.log
------ info-2022-06-29.2.log
------ info-2022-06-30.1.log
------ info-2022-06-30.2.log
------ info-2022-07-01.1.log
```

does not automatically create new date folders...
How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the rollover is performed by the RollingFileAppender.
It is likely that by the time the RollingFileAppender gets initialized the variables are already resolved - meaning that the directory's date part has become a static string.

If such variables cannot be passed into the RollingFileAppender, maybe you want to create a custom class that performs exactly such calculation. But looking at https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender it seems like the date lookups are customizable as you wish. Here is a snippet taken from teh docs that comes quite close to your demand:

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log"
        filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log.gz">
</RollingFile>
```

Comment: I verified it according to what you said, and it is true. The problem has been solved. Thank you very much!!!